# Flashbuilder 4.6 PopupManager.removePopUp

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder

The PopupManager.removePopUp leaves the blurlayer on screen when using the modal option. I have anything tried but i can't find the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Does PopupManager.visible = false work?

Comment: No that property is unknown by the PopupManager Class.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of the Flash Player 11.5.502.110?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

For me, what worked was to call the PopUpManager.removePopUp() method **after** finishing calling all the commands in the close handler callback function.

Previously, I called the PopUpManager.removePopUp(this) method within the custom window that I had previously added to the PopUpManager, but in the following line, I was calling another method (that wasn't even in the same customWindow class, but in another one). So I removed the PopUpManager.removePopUp(this) line from the customWindow, and put it at the very end of the last method in the other class.

This eliminated the problem